# Dialogflow Node.js Client - save data on data side, but don't return response

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es

I'm using DialogFlow with the official Google Node.js library. I want to use a webhook to save input data to a database, but not return a response.

However, currently I'm just waiting for the function to timeout which is slow, and writes an error to the logs `Error: No responses defined for platform: FACEBOOK`

I've checked the documentation hoping for a way to send a 200 status or similar, but haven't found anything. https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/fulfillment-library/webhook-client

Is it possible to do what I'd like to do? It seems like a fairly standard requirement.

UPDATE: My code is simple, but below

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:debug'; // enables lib debugging statements
const firebase = require('firebase-admin');
firebase.initializeApp();
const session_split = agent.session.split('/');
const session = session_split[blf_session_split.length - 1];

exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  const agent = new WebhookClient({
    request: req,
    response: res
  });

  agent.handleRequest(savedata);

  function input(agent) {
    return firebase.database().ref('/tests/' + session).update({
      "input": agent.action
    });
  }

});
```

Comment: Can you show the code you are using

Comment: Thanks @KieranQuinn - added

Comment: `response.status(200).send('Some message');`